# Unexpected behaviour when multiplying in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, math, floating-point

Currently I have 2 doubles, one price which is tax-exlcuded, and the tax percentage.

Price: 9.79 (bascially 11 but without tax)
Tax: 11%

Now what I need to do is to get the price inclusive tax again, so I do this:

```
// Tax exclusive test
double taxRate = 0.11;
double priceWithTax = 11;
double priceWithoutTax = priceWithTax * (1.0 - taxRate);

NSLog(@"priceWithoutTax = %f", priceWithoutTax);

double result = priceWithoutTax * (1 + taxRate);

NSLog(@"Result: %f", result);
```

But then upon execution my output it this:

```
priceWithoutTax = 9.790000
Result: 10.866900
```

The expected output would be 11 again. If anyone could help that would be wonderful, I checked a lot of sources around float precision but I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE (new code after answer by Bathsheba)

```
// Tax exclusive test
double taxRate = 0.11;
double priceWithTax = 11;
double priceWithoutTax = priceWithTax * (1.0 - taxRate);

NSLog(@"priceWithoutTax = %f", priceWithoutTax);

double result = priceWithoutTax / (1 - taxRate);

NSLog(@"Result: %f", result);
```

Result:

```
priceWithoutTax = 9.790000
Result: 11.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mathematics are incorrect: you need `double result = priceWithoutTax / (1.0 - taxRate);`.

Loosely speaking, floating point precision can only be blamed for errors in the 14th significant figure (for a double).

Comment: @Peter Willemsen; second pair of eyes ;-) glad to be of help.

Comment: Funny that the other formula I had was so close to a correct asnwer

Comment: @Peter Willemsen, good spot. The reason can be seen by doing a Taylor expansion of my result (1 - taxRate)^-1 (I've used ^ for power), which, to first order is 1 + taxRate; your result. The smaller the taxRate the less the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Bathsheba's answer is incorrect. His result gives you consistent answers, but your question says you are trying to take a price that includes a tax, and calculate the price of that item without the tax. For that, Bathsheba's math is incorrect.

`double result = priceWithoutTax * (1 + taxRate);` is the correct way to calculate priceWithTax.

E.g. a shirt that costs $10 not including tax plus a 5% tax will cost you a total of $10.50

`double priceWithoutTax = priceWithTax * (1.0 - taxRate);` is the **incorrect** formula for calculating priceWithoutTax from priceWithTax. Using the same example with the $10 shirt, plugging into this formula will give you `priceWithoutTax = $10.50 * (1.0 - 0.05) = $9.975`. You know is the wrong answer because you know that the shirt costs exactly $10 without tax.

The correct way to calculate priceWithoutTax: `double priceWithoutTax = priceWithTax / (1.0 + taxRate);`

Double check with the shirt again. `priceWithoutTax = $10.50 / (1.0 + 0.05) = $10`

Comment: Yes I concur. My answer was more about reconciling the unexpected result with that result from the first computation and dismissing the idea it could be due to floating point inprecision: I didn't pay any attention to the purpose of the initial computation; information on what the OP really wanted to do can be gleaned from the carefully chosen variable names and program comments (may that be a lesson to us all). Hence +1 and suggest OP review this answer carefully.